# Python Selenium error occurs while in headless state?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to grab the entire html webpage of this [website's forum](https://www.chessable.com/discussion/thread/58883/official-chessable-launch-schedule-2019/). The comment section can only be loaded once you scroll down. After some scrolling, you will find that eventually (on page 4) a **Load Next Page** button appears that you must click to get the proceeding comments. After much searching, the code below works quite well to get the to final page of comments. Much of it is taken from this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44998503/5874001) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27760083/5874001) one as well.

For reference, I am on Windows 10 and my Chrome driver version is `76.0.3809.132`. I also used PhantomJS just to see which one would load quicker. Both driver `.exe` files are placed in the same directory as the one I'm executing the script from. I have  not encountered any issues up until today.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def scrollDownAllTheWay(driver):
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100*document.body.scrollHeight);")

        time.sleep(3)

        if "Load next page</button>" in driver.page_source:
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.myButton').click()

        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

#Load this and comment out chrome headless code below, if needed.
#driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

#Chrome driver
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.chessable.com/discussion/thread/58883/official-chessable-launch-schedule-2019/")

scrollDownAllTheWay(driver)
```

When I run the script above with `webdriver.PhantomJS()` (replacing the Chrome portion with it), I have no issues. The function runs until it the headless browser reaching the last page. Great.

When I run the script below with `webdriver.Chrome()` headless, I run into the following error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button id="load-next-comments" class="myButton">...</button> is not clickable at point (388, 23). Other element would receive the click: <div class="headerHolder">...</div>   (Session info: headless chrome=76.0.3809.132)
```

I couldn't find anything *that* helpful to solve this problem. Even more strange is that if you disable the `options.add_argument("--headless")` part (comment it out), the page loads just fine, and completes the entire page's scroll. I can see the final clicks execute in my local Chrome browser, then see it stop scrolling & clicking when it has completed.

Question: **Why is the headless Chrome session not properly working here, but the non-headless version is?**

**Edit:** I just found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779520/elementclickinterceptedexception-element-click-intercepted), which could be potentially helpful, but I am not sure.

Note: I'm open to using other browser drivers like `FireFox()` or anything else as a potential workaround, but still the question remains.

Comment: use this url - `https://www.chessable.com/ajax/discussionComments.php?threadId=58883&page=1&perPage=500&order=best`   simple!! you really dont need selenium and headless if you want only comments, i would suggest go for request lib

Comment: @Dev Wow, you saved me a lot of work. Thanks! Would you be able to share any insights about ajax? How did you find/construct that URL? I'm in my infancy of webscraping.

Comment: F12 for developer tools, then click on metwork tab. You can also filter for XHRs

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks to both of you. I appreciate it. This works as a nice alternative to the OP. I would have never thought about this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Chromedriver.

Solved it by adding these options to my code:

```
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

PS: I found the solution here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4685

Answer (score 2):

Recently I also stumbled upon this problem. After much of debugging and researching I figured out one logical explanation as to why the code work in **non-headless** mode and gives the same error as you in **headless mode**.

This is because in **headless mode** if you don't specify the size of the chrome window (by `driver.set_window_rect(width=1200, height=900)`) then there might be a pop up that would cover the clickable button and hence prevent it from getting clicked.

So, ideally giving the window an explicit size will make all the pop-up reside to their particular place and prevent hiding of the button that you want to click.

Specifying the window size worked for me and I think it should work for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's an element on top of that button that's making it not clickable.
If you change:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.myButton').click()
```

to

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('.myButton').click()")
```

It should work. In fact, doing everything from javascript is not a bad idea unless you're "QA testing"

Answer (score 1):

`JavaScript` is not required.If you set the `window-size` on `headless` mode it will click on the next_page button.Hope this will help.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def scrollDownAllTheWay(driver):
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100*document.body.scrollHeight);")

        time.sleep(3)

        if "Load next page</button>" in driver.page_source:

            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.myButton').click()
            print('clicked')

        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.chessable.com/discussion/thread/58883/official-chessable-launch-schedule-2019/")

scrollDownAllTheWay(driver)
```

---

To verify that whether code working or not just take screenshot before or after and you will come to know it is working.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def scrollDownAllTheWay(driver):
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    i = 1
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100*document.body.scrollHeight);")

        time.sleep(3)

        if "Load next page</button>" in driver.page_source:
            driver.save_screenshot("screenshot_{}.png".format(i))
            i = i+1
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.myButton').click()
            driver.save_screenshot("screenshot_{}.png".format(i))
            i = i + 1
            print('clicked')

        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.chessable.com/discussion/thread/58883/official-chessable-launch-schedule-2019/")

scrollDownAllTheWay(driver)
```